# Oracle sql - Read data from a file for IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to read data from a file to supply the data for IN clause?

```
SQL> SELECT a,b from TABLE123 where type=10 and values IN('file.txt');
```

The file.txt has list of values.

I cannot use a subquery because the table on which the subquery is to be applied in on a different database.

**EDIT:** I would prefer not to create a temporary table

Comment: If you don't want to create a temporary table you'd have to use `utl_file` to read the contents and build up a collection of values, and that still assumes the file is on the server. Or use SQL\*Loader but you'd still need a staging table for that. Or build your query in a shell script before calling SQL\*Plus. Why don't you want to use an external table?

Comment: A different database should not be an issue as long as the database you are working from has a dblink pointing to the other database. Read up on dblinks here if you are not familiar with them: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm. If the powers that be do not allow it, that's another story then. :-/

Answer (score 2):

assuming that you have copied the "file.txt" file to the Oracle server (under: 'ext_tab_data' directory):

```
CREATE TABLE countries_ext (
  country_code      VARCHAR2(5),
  country_name      VARCHAR2(50),
  country_language  VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      country_code      CHAR(5),
      country_name      CHAR(50),
      country_language  CHAR(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Countries1.txt','Countries2.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Please find details [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i)...

Here is your SQL:

```
SELECT a,b from TABLE123 
where type=10 
and values IN(select country_code from countries_ext);
```

PS off course you can replace your files, which would replace the contents of your external table...

Comment: Is it possible without creating a table?

Comment: Alternatively you can use Oracle SQL loader in order to load your CSV/TEXT file into already existing table.

Answer (score 0):

Directly as stated, no. Somewhere a table-like entity must be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind copying and editing your text file, you can copy the text file to file.sql, add `SELECT a,b from TABLE123 where type=10 and values IN(` to the beginning of the file, and `);` to the end of the file and add commas and quotes as needed to each line of the file.

Then from SQL*Plus you can just run the file:

```
SQL> @file.sql
```

Otherwise no, there's no way to do it without *temporarily* getting the file data into a table of some sort.  @MaxU referenced the method I would choose to use.

Comment: Since the number of values are more than 1000 I cannot give everything inside IN? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Every few hundred lines you could also add `) union all SELECT a,b from TABLE123 where type=10 and values IN(` to your file.  Where there's a will there's a way ;^)